# Trying to predict gender for my dataset using opensource library but is only showing male in the predicted gender

Tags: python, open-source

My dataset has a Name and gender column and I am trying an open-source library to predict the gender using

```
    from guess_indian_gender import IndianGenderPredictor
    i = IndianGenderPredictor()
    dfna['predicted_gender'] = i.predict(name = dfna['name'])
```

But instead of working on every row, it is showing me male value for every row

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 dfna['predicted_gender'] = dfna[‘name’].apply(lambda x: i.predict(x))
```

If it’s still showing all Male it may be that the classification is bias towards males, which may be due to features used in the model.